# Why does SSRS start displaying #Error in a field when I change page, but works fine initially?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Odd one.

I have a report which basically returns a list of staff absences - there's a row per continuous period of absence listing the dates, number of days the absence lasted and then finally a column which displays the number of absences.

The report works fine initially displaying everything as I would expect, as below:

However, if I change to the second page the Occasions column stops displaying the figures and displays `#Error` instead. If I then change back to page 1 it continues to show `#Error` even though it was working perfectly when the report rendered:

Likewise, if I export to Excel it displays `#Value` instead of the data. The Occasions column is simply `=Code.GetNumAbsences(Fields!Staff_Code.Value)`. The custom code that it's calling is...

```
Public Function GetNumAbsences(ByVal staffCode As String) As Integer

    Return CInt(MyTable(staffCode)(3)) 

End Function
```

MyTable is just a HashTable with a string (staffCode) as the Key, and the 3rd item is just an Integer. I have no idea why the report would suddenly throw an error after changing page when it works fine at runtime. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What is the expression in the `Occasions` column?

Comment: Ugh, sorry I thought I'd added that. Let me update my Question

Comment: @SébastienSevrin - I have updated my question, apologies for missing it off before!